# Add Trailing Slash for certain page types

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to add a trailing slash for certain static page types like `.html`, `.asp` and `.pdf`.

I tried the following code in `.htaccess` but it is adding a trailing slash to all types of links.

```
# Force trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

My site bought from a previous owner has many `.html`, `.asp` and `.pdf` pages which are now showing server errors in Google webmaster tools. Now I am using WordPress default permalink structure and with the redirection plugin, those static pages are not redirecting unless I force a trailing slash on them.

Comment: "now showing server errors" - presumably you mean 404s? (Although these aren't strictly "server errors".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting to append a trailing slash so you can use the "redirection plugin" to redirect these requests *again* doesn't make a whole lot of sense. (This would seem to suggest that these "static pages" still exist? Although the directives you posted suggest otherwise?)

Anyway, to answer your question (assuming these pages *don't* exist)...

Your current `RewriteRule` targets every URL (ie. `(.*)`), so it naturally appends a trailing slash to all URLs. You need to target just the URLs that end `.html`, `.asp` and `.pdf`. And if you do this you don't need the *condition* that checks that a trailing slash is not already present on the URL-path.

I don't think you really need to check the `REQUEST_METHOD` either?

So, this could be written:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+\.(?:html|asp|pdf))$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Awesome, your code is working perfectly. :) Thanks for your nice help.Yes you are correct, those static pages do not exist and I am redirecting some valuable pages of them to get their link value.